# Batch to change Mac Address Windows XP Pro

Tags: batch-file, registry, mac-address, windows-xp-sp3

Hey guys I need to know how to change the MAC Address of my pc, I know that it has something to do with the registry and I dont like to dig into that to much, reason being, if something is messed up its messed up for good. I dont have any starter code to go on. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

see

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address /?
```

This should do what you want.

**EDIT**: I wrote this program some years ago. 
Use whatever you need from it.
Note that you may have to adapt "LAN-Verbindung" to your adaptername (find it with 'ipconfig')
Also sorry for the german "how-to", I don't know how those menues are named in english. - But maybe, you don't have needs for an DHCP-Server.

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="home" goto home
if "%1"=="office" goto office
if "%1"=="dhcp" goto dhcp
if "%1"=="server" goto server
goto help

REM set ip-address to parameter
netsh interface ip set address "LAN-Verbindung" static %1 255.255.255.0
goto ende

:dhcp         rem work as DHCP-Client
netsh interface ip set address "LAN-Verbindung" dhcp
goto ende

:server       rem work as DHCP-Server
netsh interface ip set address "LAN-Verbindung" static 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
goto ende

:home         rem fixed Address at home
netsh interface ip set address "LAN-Verbindung" static 192.168.178.30 255.255.255.0 192.168.178.1 1
goto ende

:office         rem fixed Address at office
 netsh interface ip set address "LAN-Verbindung" static 192.168.0.5 255.255.255.0 
goto ende

:help
echo.
echo Syntax: ip [parameter]
echo Parameter:
echo  home              set a fixed IP (predefined) 
echo  work              set a fixed IP (predefined)
echo  server            set a fixed IP (predefined) and works as DHCP-Server
echo  dhcp              works as DHCP-Client
echo  [IP-Adresse]      set a fixed IP (defined by parameter
echo Examples:
echo   ip 192.168.1.44   sets IP to 192.168.1.44
echo   ip server         sets IP to 192.168.0.1 and starts DHCP-Server
echo   ip home           sets IP to a fixed (predefined) IP
echo   ip dhcp           fetches an IP from DHCP-Server
echo ATTENTION: to work as DHCP-Server, the "Gemeinsame Nutzung der
echo          Internetverbindung" aktiviert werden (has to be done only one time).
echo     Netzwerkverbindungen "Eigenschaften"
echo       LAN-Verbindung "Eigenschaften" 
echo         "Erweitert" "Anderen Benutzern im Netzwerk gestatten..." aktivieren
echo HINT: This Batch-file needs Administrator-rights
echo.
REM  the IP-Range for den DHCP-Server can be determined to a smaller range.
REM  Info see: http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=230248
goto ende2

:ende
ipconfig
:ende2
echo.
```

Comment: could you please explain this a bit im confused in the command syntax, theres nothing that allows me to change the MAC only gateway and static ips @Stephan

Comment: ah sorry, you meant the hardwareaddress of the nic. You know, that every NIC in the world has it's _unique_ adress, and you will get into trouble with connections, if it is _not_ unique?

Answer (score 0):

On my own PC, I have a Realtek PCIe card, and I can specify a hardware (MAC) address this way.

1. On Windows 7,  try going to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections.
2. Select your network adapter and right-click to open the context menu
3. Select Properties.  A window pops up with the Networking tab.
4. Click the Configure button beneath the name of your network adapter.
5. Click the Advanced Tab.
6. Select the Network Address property.

Here's a link to a Superuser.com thread with a screenshot: 
[Advanced parameters for realtek pci-e gbe family network card](https://superuser.com/questions/248937/advanced-parameters-for-realtek-pci-e-gbe-family-network-card)

You can also research [MAC Spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) for further information.